# Show continuity of limit function $\lim: c\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, normed-spaces

> Let be $c$ the set of convergent real valued sequences equipped with the supremum norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty}$ and $F:c\to\mathbb{R}$ with $F(f):=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(k)$, where $f(k)$ denotes the $k$-th member of the convergent seuqence $f$. Show that $F$ is continuous by using the **sequential definition of continuity**, i.e. show for an arbitrary sequence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}F(f_n)=F\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n\right)$.

**My approach:**

Let be $\epsilon>0$ and $f\in c$ with $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f(k):=a$ and $(f_n)_{n\to\infty}$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n=f$, all arbitrary but fixed. Due to both convergences there exist two indices $n_0,k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\Vert f_n-f\Vert_{\infty}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n>n_0$ and $|f(k)-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $k>k_0$. Further,
$$
|f_n(k)-a|\leq |f_n(k)-f(k)|+|f(k)-a|,\text{ for all }k\in\mathbb{N},
$$
where $f_n(k)$ and $f(k)$ denote the $k$-th member of the repective sequence. Let be $n>n_0$ and $k>k_0$, then
$$
|f_n(k)-a|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.
$$
Which means that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f_n=a$ and finally
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}F(f_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f_n(k)=a=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f(k)=F(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n).
$$
As $f$ was chosen arbitrarily function $F$ is continuous.

---

Is this correct?

Comment: Your solution is correct but too complicated for my taste. Just observe that $\lvert F(f) \rvert \leq \lVert f \lVert_\infty$ and you are done since $F$ is a linear functional.

Comment: Did you mean "sequential definition of continuity"? Because "continuity definition of sequences" implies that you are defining the concept of "sequence" using the pre-existing concept of "continuity", not the other way around.